# Can log likelihood function be negative

Tags: aic, likelihood

I do some optimization problem in R. I minimize the loglikelihood function. I found that the log-likelihood has a negative value. For example, I have this: -34.5. Then, when I count the AIC, I will get, a positive value for AIC. My question, Is it ok to have negative loglikelihood values (I am working with continuous data).

Comment: Is this probably a duplicate? I would not be surprised to find that the question has been asked before.

Comment: It's certainly a duplicate.

Comment: For example, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172846/negative-log-marginal-likelihood-0 (the fact that it's marginal changes nothing on this issue); that one is closed in turn because its a duplicate of the oft-asked question about densities exceeding 1. That one is probably sufficient but I think there's better ones to be had.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The likelihood function is defined as

$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta|X) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_\theta(X_i)
$$

and is a product of probability mass functions (discrete variables) or probability density functions (continuous variables) $f_\theta$ parametrized by $\theta$ and evaluated at the $X_i$ points.

Probability densities are non-negative, while probabilities also are less or equal to one. It follows that their product cannot be negative. The [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) function is negative for values less than one and positive for values greater than one. So yes, it is possible that you end up with a negative value for log-likelihood (for discrete variables it will always be so).

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer.  I am working on a project and I would like to clearly understand it. Could you advise me on some peer-review paper or a book about this, please? this will be very helpful to discuss it with my supervisor.

Comment: @Maryam this should be explained in any mathematical statistics handbook, since follows from the definitions.

Comment: In principle any probability or probability density being 0 means that the likelihood is 0 and the log-likelihood is indeterminate. In principle also saying that the likelihood is zero amounts to saying that some observed data are impossible and that surely means a misspecified model. So in practice only positive values for $f$ enter your equation.